# Symbolically prove that two expressions are identical

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, proof

I encountered this problem when trying to reproduce the result of [this paper](http://appliedmechanics.asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/article.aspx?articleid=1394556). *(The relevant parts are all included in the preview i.e. the 1st page of the article. This link is just given as background information, the following question is still self-contained without it.)*

I want to prove `int == intpaper` assuming `l > 0, τ > 0` where

```
int = 
  Sqrt[3] (-(1/((Sqrt[-3 + 2 Sqrt[3]] l - I Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[3]] τ) 
      Sqrt[1 + 3/(Sqrt[-3 + 2 Sqrt[3]] l - I Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[3]] τ)^2])) - 
    1/((Sqrt[-3 + 2 Sqrt[3]] l + I Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[3]] τ) 
      Sqrt[1 + 3/(Sqrt[-3 + 2 Sqrt[3]] l + I Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[3]] τ)^2])); 

intpaper = Im[2/Sqrt[-1 - (Sqrt[-1 + Sqrt[3]] l - 2 I τ)^2/(3 + Sqrt[3])]];
```

It's easy to verify their equivalence numerically.

```
Block[{l, τ}, {l, τ} = RandomReal[1, 2]; intpaper == int]
```

always returns `True`. But I don't know how to verify it symbolically. I tried

```
Simplify[int == intpaper, {l > 0, τ > 0}]
```

but it was returned unevaluated.

Comment: Since all the variables are real, why not do a preliminary `ComplexExpand[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Just tried, but at least `Simplify[int == intpaper // ComplexExpand, {l > 0, τ > 0}]` doesn't help. The `Im` is rather troublesome.

Comment: `ComplexExpand` is only going to make things worse because you get irreducible `Arg`s.

Comment: @Feyre, even with an explicit `TargetFunctions` setting?

Comment: @J.M. I don't see how you can really get anywhere useful with Target Functions in this case, but point taken on a throwaway comment.

Comment: An alternative form would be     -2 Sqrt[3]Re[1/Sqrt[ 3 - 1/2 Sqrt[3] (-2 + Sqrt[3]) (Sqrt[2] l + 2 I Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[3]] \[Tau])^2]]

Comment: @yarchik Oh, how did you find this?

Comment: @xzczd Well, it is MA-assisted, but not fully automatic. Therefore I have not put it as a solution. Actually, I like your question very much. I had similar problems several times and always ended up with semi-automatic solutions. I would be very interested if some can suggest a fully automatic approach.

Comment: You might consider providing a open-access link to the publication (possibly after uploading the pdf there by yourself, since the copyright issues are likely to be long expired), so that everybody can access it.

Comment: Maybe this is **mathematics** problem, rather than a **Mathematica** problem.

Comment: @anderstood It's not quite necessary actually, because the paper is short (Only 2 pages) and the relevant part is already shown in the preview i.e. the first page, and that link is just given as background information, without that my question is still answerable. I'll edit my question to note this.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG I think there's no doubt that it's a _Mathematica_ problem: I have a equation and **I'm sure it's correct**, now I want to verify it with _Mathematica_ (notice **I don't need a step-to-step proof**) but `Simplify` doesn't work, can I achieve the goal with other built-in functions/options or a minimal effort of coding? These are all about the usage of _Mathematica_.

Comment: Why did you emphasize the **self-contained**? This is just a question, you just need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 4):

<s>This solution gets a trivial step away from the answer.</s>
(Strikeout after addressing the comments.)

You can consider the difference `diff = int - intpaper`, and check that it vanishes.

Rather than having Mathematica take the imaginary part, do it "by hand":

```
intpaperz = 
2/Sqrt[-1 - (Sqrt[-1 + Sqrt[3]] l - 2 I \[Tau])^2/(3 + Sqrt[3])];
intpaperzc = 
2/Sqrt[-1 - (Sqrt[-1 + Sqrt[3]] l + 2 I \[Tau])^2/(3 + Sqrt[3])];
intpaper = 1/(2 I) (intpaperz - intpaperzc);
```

which uses $\textrm{Im}(z) = (z-z^*)/(2i)$. Note: I assume $\tau$ and $l$ are real.

By inspection of the  the resulting expression for `diff`:

[image: Expression]

a good change of variables appears to be

$$a = \sqrt{6-2\sqrt{3}} \tau , \quad b = l \sqrt{-3 + 2\sqrt{3}} ,$$

which can be implemeneted by:

```
out = FullSimplify[
  diff /. {\[Tau] -> a/Sqrt[6 - 2 Sqrt[3]], 
    l -> b/Sqrt[-3 + 2 Sqrt[3]]}]
```

The resulting expression is

[image: Expression 2]

This suggests another change of variables:

```
out = out /. {a + I b -> w, a - I b -> wc, -I a + b -> -I w, I a + b -> I wc};
FullSimplify[out]
```

[image]

<s>This is the trivial last step that I stopped fighting Mathematica on. 
For a complex number (such as `w` and `wc`), it's true that $\sqrt{w^2} = w$, so both terms vanish.</s>
This last step is not so trivial. As @xzczd pointed out in the comment, this only vanishes if $\textrm{Re}(w)>0$ and $\textrm{Re}(w^*)> 0$. Well,

$$\textrm{Re}(w) = a = \sqrt{6-2\sqrt{3}} \tau $$

and

$$\textrm{Re}(w^*) = a ,$$
so I guess $\tau\ge 0$ in the original problem statement.

In Mathematica:

```
FullSimplify[out,{Re@w > 0, Re@wc > 0}];
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: I guess the more generally applicable answer is to try to change variables that un-clutter the expression before simplifying.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Then, "For a complex number (such as `w` and `wc`), it's true that $\sqrt{w^2}=w$, so both terms vanish." I'm afraid it's not true, a counter example is `w -> -1 + I`. I'm not familiar with complex analysis, but I think one sufficient condition for $\sqrt{w^2}=w$ is `Re@w>0`, and this is indeed satisfied, given `a -> (6 - 2 Sqrt[3]) \[Tau]`. You can add `{Re@w > 0, Re@wc > 0}` to `Simplify` to make it output `0`.

Comment: Hah, sorry for the incorrect statement about $\sqrt{w^2}$ - as you say, they are not equal in general. I guess the correct statement is that the two expressions only match if $\textrm{Re}(w) > 0$ and $\textrm{Im}(w) = \textrm{Im}(w^*) >0$ (`wc` $ = w^*$).

Comment: Er… I think there're some typos? The $Im(w)=$ seems to be redundant, and the `lc` and `\[Tau]c` at beginning should be `l` and `\[Tau]`?

Comment: Yeah, the `lc` and `\[Tau]c` happened from accidentally closing the window and having an old version restored - I corrected them. And in my previous comment, I meant $\textrm{Im}(w)= \textrm{Re}(w^∗)>0$ (which I at least got right in the answer). Sorry about that!

Comment: …But $w=a+i b$ and $w^{*}=a - i b$, so $Im(w)=b \neq Re(w^{*})=a$, right?

Comment: Wow, yep. I've even taught complex analysis in the past (not recently, clearly). I'll edit out the offending part of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

My solution is in the [experimental mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_mathematics) style:

```
Series[int - intpaper, {τ, \[Infinity], 12}] // Normal // FullSimplify
(* 0 *)
```

You have to believe that if two series expansions are equal up to 12th order this is an identity. Advantage of the approach is its unbeatable simplicity. Of course, sceptics with faster computers can verify even higher orders. However, it can never be made fully rigorous, but what is verity after all?

Comment: Normally, in the series approach, you want to first make sure that a differential equation of appropriate order is satisfied (using e.g. `DifferentialRootReduce[]`), and then use `Series[]` to expand up to an appropriate order to check that what should be zero is actually zero.

Comment: Though not that perfect, this approach is indeed more automatic, so 千金市骨 :)

Comment: @xzczd Thank you! Your post gives an example showing that not all MA algorithms are equally strong, and it might be useful to try different things.