# How to prove this algebraic identity?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I mean
$$\forall z \in \mathbb C\left(\ \left| \sqrt{z^2-1}-z\right| +\left| z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right| =| z-1| +| z+1|\right ) .$$

The command

```
ComplexPlot3D[Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] + z] + Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - z] - Abs[z - 1] -
Abs[z + 1] // Chop, {z, -3 - 3*I, 3 + 3*I}]
```

[image]

confirms it, but this is not a proof. Here are my unsuccessful attempts.

```
ForAll[z, Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] + z] + Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - z] ==
Abs[z - 1] + Abs[z + 1]]
Resolve[%, Complexes]
```

is running without any response for hours. The same issue with

```
Reduce[Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] + z] + Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - z] ==
Abs[z - 1] + Abs[z + 1], z]
```

The command

```
FindInstance[Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] + z] + Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - z] != Abs[z - 1] + Abs[z + 1], z]
```

returns the input. A few other attempts (for example, with `Solve`) are omitted.

Comment: Hard problem (I sincerely hope I'm wrong). Somewhat related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/119346/1871

Comment: @xzczd: Thank you for your interest to the question. I'd like to quote Piet Hein; "ORIGINALITY
Original thought
is a straightforward process.
It's easy enough
when you know what to do.
You simply combine
in appropriate doses
the blatantly false
and the patently true"

Comment: and "
PROBLEMS

Problems worthy
  of attack
prove their worth
  by hitting back
"

Comment: With a bit of cheating  (Abs-> Sqrt[#^2] output of  Resolve[ForAll[{z}, 
  Sqrt[(Sqrt[z^2 - 1] + z)^2] + Sqrt[(Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - z)^2] - 
    Sqrt[(z - 1)^2] - Sqrt[(z + 1)^2] == 0]] is  False, which I don't believe. Since replacing ForAll by Exists and testing ==, <, > supports your conjecture.

Comment: @Acus; Mathematica is right; `Abs[z]!=Sqrt[z^2]` for complex values of `z`. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @PeterMortensen and others: Please, don't edit my questions in such manner: from "How to prove this algebraic identity?" to "How can I prove this algebraic identity?" Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since both sides are positive, the identity is valid if the square of left hand side equals the square of right hand side.

$\forall z \in \mathbb C \; \; \; \left(\ \left| \sqrt{z^2-1}-z\right| +\left| z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right| \right )^2 = \left( | z-1| +| z+1| \right)^2 .$

To verify in *Mathematica*:

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[(Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] + z] + Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - z])^2, z]]    
        
(* 2 (1 + Abs[z]^2 + Sqrt[(-1 + z^2) (-1 + Conjugate[z]^2)]) *)

FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[(Abs[z - 1] + Abs[z + 1])^2, z]]
        
(* 2 (1 + Abs[z]^2 + Sqrt[(-1 + z^2) (-1 + Conjugate[z]^2)]) *)
```

Comment: Wow, surprisingly simple! I'm happy to see I'm wrong :) .

Comment: How does this prove of disprove the statement?

Answer (score 9):

The function

```
f[w_]:=Abs[Sinh[w]-Cosh[w]]+Abs[Sinh[w]+Cosh[w]]-Abs[Cosh[w]-1]-Abs[Cosh[w]+1]
```

vanishes:

```
f[u+I*v]//ComplexExpand//FullSimplify[#,Element[u|v,Reals]]&
(* 0 *)
```

Therefore `f[ArcCosh[z]]` vanishes, and this is OPs identity.

Comment: Thanks for this `Element[u|v,Reals]` trick, I had been using `And[Element[u,Reals],Element[v,Reals]]` for similar problems

Comment: @Diffycue - you could also use `Element[{u, v}, Reals]` which if you look at the `FullForm` is stored as `Element[u | v, Reals]`

Comment: Clever but sadly still not rigorous, because `Sinh[ArcCosh[z]] == Sqrt[z^2 - 1]` doesn't always hold.

Comment: For every complex number $z$ there is some other complex number $w$ such that $(z,\sqrt{z^2-1}) = (\cosh w, \sinh w)$.

Comment: @user293787: Unfortunately, `ForAll[z, Exists[w, z == Cosh[w] && Sqrt[1 - z^2] == Sinh[w]]] :Resolve[%, Complexes]` performs `False`.

Comment: You have a typo, using `Sqrt[z^2-1]` you get `True`.

Comment: @user293787:+1. You are right. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: “For every complex number $z$…” I suggest adding this line to the body of answer :) .

Answer (score 1):

Your `ComplexPlot3D` is a good test for the numerical exactness of the methods used by this Mathematica built-in for this task. Try to play around with the numerical exactness values for Your session.

Just in case You like a serious answer from Mathematica use:

```
 FindInstance[
 Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] + z] + Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - z] == 
  Abs[z - 1] + Abs[z + 1], z, Complexes, 1]
```

(* {{z -> 0}} *)

I selected $n=1$, but there are infinitely many solutions because this is an identity. If $n>1$ is chosen, the given routines searches infinitely long again.

The error message `FindInstance::nsmet` is by the use of this additional option gone. nsmet is an abbreviation for Namespace methods. So this is a very broad and not so in-depth error message.

The noise in Your `ComplexPlot3D` is of the size of $$MachinePrecision (*15.9546*)$. So Mathematica uses the chance to show residual noise. You might choose to suppress this by using option to `ComplexPlot3D` `PlotRange`

```
ComplexPlot3D[
 Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] + z] + Abs[Sqrt[z^2 - 1] - z] - Abs[z - 1] - 
   Abs[z + 1] // Chop, {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.0, 15. 10^-15}]
```

[image: flattened result]

It is a not so rarely discussed topic, why does Mathematica produce that often the very same noise pattern for specified problems?

I used the default color theme for my plot.